# Need to change the build status depending upon the test result of Selenium test cases. How can i check the result and change the status?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I need to modify the build status to success or failure depending upon the test result from TestNG test results. So, if there are 90% test cases are passed then the build status should change to successful. I want the groovy script that can do that. As of now, I have this but it still throws errors in Jenkins.

```
                      def run = Jenkins.instance().getItemByFullName(env.JOB_NAME).getBuildByNumber(env.BUILD_NUMBER)
                      def testResults = run.getAction(hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction.class)
                      def total = testResults.totalCount
                      def failed = testResults.failCount
                      def skipped = testResults.skipCount
                      def passCount = total - failed - skipped
                      def listener = currentBuild.rawBuild.listener
                      listener.getLogger().println("Total: ${total}")
                      listener.getLogger().println("Failed: ${failed}")
                      listener.getLogger().println("Skipped: ${skipped}")
                      listener.getLogger().println("Passed: ${passCount}")

                      def passPercentage = Math.round((passCount / total.toDouble()) * 100)
                      if (passPercentage >= 90) {
                          currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
                      } else {
                          currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                      }
```